# update entry IF values to set is different, else update only 1 column

Tags: mysql

I have table:

```
job  | startDate           | EndDate             | Status 
3221 | 2014-08-12 12:00:00 | 2014-08-12 15:00:00 | 1
```

I have two cases here:
this contains same startDate and EndDate values, which means I need no actual update on entry:

```
UPDATE jobs SET startDate='2014-08-12 12:00:00', EndDate='2014-08-12 15:00:00' WHERE job=3221
```

In this case, I have slighly different value EndDate (may be startDate as well or both)
So I have to update values which was actually changed (are not same), and update STATUS from 1 to 0 (since update values before was not the same) any ideas how to achieve that in one query?

```
UPDATE jobs SET startDate='2014-08-12 12:00:00', EndDate='2014-08-13 19:00:00' WHERE job=3221
```

Comment: you want to update only the records that have a different Start and End date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`job` int, `startDate` datetime, `EndDate` datetime, `Status` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`job`, `startDate`, `EndDate`, `Status`)
VALUES
    (3221, '2014-08-12 12:00:00', '2014-08-12 15:00:00', 1),
    (3222, '2014-08-12 12:00:00', '2014-08-12 15:00:00', 1)
;

UPDATE t
SET Status = IF(startDate = '2014-08-12 12:00:00' AND EndDate = '2014-08-12 15:00:00', 1, 0),
startDate = '2014-08-12 12:00:00',
EndDate = '2014-08-12 15:00:00'
WHERE job = 3221;

UPDATE t
SET Status = IF(startDate = '2014-08-12 12:00:00' AND EndDate = '2014-08-13 19:00:00', 1, 0),
startDate = '2014-08-12 12:00:00',
EndDate = '2014-08-13 19:00:00'
WHERE job = 3222;

SELECT * FROM t;

|  JOB |                     STARTDATE |                       ENDDATE | STATUS |
|------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|--------|
| 3221 | August, 12 2014 12:00:00+0000 | August, 12 2014 15:00:00+0000 |      1 |
| 3222 | August, 12 2014 12:00:00+0000 | August, 13 2014 19:00:00+0000 |      0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use case statment

```
UPDATE Table
     Case WHEN <Condition>              
          THEN set statue=0 
          ELSE set status=1 END
```

Comment: well for me personally syntax of this one looks weird (even so i'm sure it's probably correct, though), I note this one, though fancyPants looks more simple to remember. :)

Answer (score 1):

here's a simplier version:

```
UPDATE jobs 
SET    StartDate = '2014-08-12 12:00:00', 
       EndDate = '2014-08-13 19:00:00',
       `Status` = DATE(StartDate) = DATE(EndDate)       -- returns 1 (true) or 0
WHERE  job = 3221
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/858af/1)

Comment: Well that's looks a bit weird, i mean if i read if years ago, I would have to think what x = y = z means, I prefer fancyPants version, it has quite clear IF statement, with true/false values.

Any impact on performance though?

Comment: @Laimonas `x = y = z` is the same with `x = (y = z)` where `(y = z)` is a boolean expression.

Comment: well I understand that, but like I said, after A while, It would looks just not clear enough, I would need search (or run query to see how it works) to really get it (of course with practice comes knowledge). Though, I still prefer fancyPants version, because of more clear syntax, as extra in his version you can define 'status' value, so it not necessary has to be Boolean, so it's more practical i guess..

Well that's my personal opinion, that not necessarily means that his code is better or something, as extra I'm just learning though